# Python multiprocessing within class: OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am looking to add a background task to my Class in python. the overall class would be managing one websocket connection to discord.

In order to do this, I need to have a background task that runs a "heartbeat" or a constant blocking task.
I also require to be able to turn off this task, upon killing the connection

For the sake of demonstration, I reduced the entire code down to its bare roots.

Here is a working verison

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import websocket
import time


class DiscordAgent:
    def connect(self):
        x = mp.Process(target=self.heartbeat)
        x.start()

    def heartbeat(self):
        while True:
            print("the heart is beating")
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    agent = DiscordAgent()
    agent.connect()
```

But when I add these two lines of code: it breaks

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import websocket
import time


class DiscordAgent:
    def connect(self):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocket()
        self.ws.connect(
            "wss://gateway.discord.gg/?encoding=json&v=9&compress=zlib-stream"
        )
        x = mp.Process(target=self.heartbeat)
        x.start()

    def heartbeat(self):
        while True:
            print("the heart is beating")
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    agent = DiscordAgent()
    agent.connect()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Coding\csj\polaris-back\test2.py", line 23, in <module>
    agent.connect()
  File "f:\Coding\csj\polaris-back\test2.py", line 13, in connect
    x.start()
  File "C:\Users\noahl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\noahl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\noahl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\noahl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\noahl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Users\noahl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 273, in __getstate__
    raise TypeError(f"cannot pickle {self.__class__.__name__!r} object")
TypeError: cannot pickle 'SSLSocket' object
(venv) PS F:\Coding\csj\polaris-back> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\noahl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 102, in spawn_main
    source_process = _winapi.OpenProcess(
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

These two lines of code are super mysterious to me XD, it has something to do with how `Process` works.
Please! Help me out!

I have tried implementing other solutions from searches on google. threading will not seem to work as I cannot terminate the process when I need to. All of the other solutions around Process also do not involve classes.

This seems to be a very mysterious issue, as inserting only these 2 lines breaks it.

Comment: But you don't state how it breaks! Are you getting a `pickle` error? You need to post a stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a web socket in the main process in method `connect` with the statement `self.ws = websocket.WebSocket()`. Then you are creating a new process whose target is `self.heartbeat`. Because method `heartbeat` is running in another process (address space), the entire `DiscordAgent` object (instance) must be sent over to that new address space by serializing it with `pickle` and then de-serialzing the *pickled* object in the new address space. But there are certain objects that cannot be serialized, such as sockets. Can the connection be done in the `heartbeat` method or can the socket be created after the process is created. Examples:

**Example 1**

```py
class DiscordAgent:
    def connect(self):
        x = mp.Process(target=self.heartbeat)
        x.start()

    def heartbeat(self):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocket()
        self.ws.connect(
            "wss://gateway.discord.gg/?encoding=json&v=9&compress=zlib-stream"
        )

        while True:
            print("the heart is beating")
            time.sleep(1)
```

**Example 2**

```py
class DiscordAgent:
    def connect(self):
        x = mp.Process(target=self.heartbeat)
        x.start()

        self.ws = websocket.WebSocket()
        self.ws.connect(
            "wss://gateway.discord.gg/?encoding=json&v=9&compress=zlib-stream"
        )

    def heartbeat(self):
        while True:
            print("the heart is beating")
            time.sleep(1)
```

If the `hearbeat` method needs access to the socket, then only example 1 will work for you. But the bottom line is that a socket connection cannot be shared among processes.

However, you can have have `DiscordantAgent` start `heartbeat` in a thread and if threads needs to do CPU-intensive work, they can do that work in a new process. But if terminating the thread is an issue, try passing to `heartbeat` a `threading.Event` instance that is can periodically checked to see if another thread has called `set()` on it (see the docs) and terminate if it has been set.

Comment: Yes, this is a perfect explanation of the problem, thank you.
My new issue is I do need to have the websocket connect shared amongst 2 processes. You can sortove imagine it as 2 constant loops in the background.

My question is if Process will not be able to do this, what alternatives are there?

Comment: I mentioned that those "processes" need to be threads and that if something occurs that requires that they be terminated, then this termination must be done cooperatively by the threads themselves. You could pass "termination" event to the threads and then when there is some occurrence requiring these threads to terminate, you call `set` on the event. The threads do have to periodically test to see if the event has been set. Since the threads probably won't need to wait on the event, i.e. blocking until the event is set, you can also just use a "stop" attribute that gets set to True.

Comment: Another possibility is that if the threads are created with *daemon=True* and then started, they will automatically terminate when the main thread terminates. Whether that works for you only you can say; I can't tell from what you posted.